# Why do Unicode characters show up properly in database, but as ? when printed in Java via Hibernate?

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, unicode, utf-8

I'm writing a webapp, and interfacing with MySQL using Hibernate 3.5.  Using "デスクトップ ინგლისური" as my test string, I can input the string and see that it is properly persisted into the database.  However, when I later pull the value out of the database and print to the console as a String, I see "?????? ?????????".  If I use

```
new OutputStreamWriter(System.out,"UTF-8");
```

then I get "„Éá„Çπ„ÇØ„Éà„ÉÉ„Éó ·Éò·Éú·Éí·Éö·Éò·É°·É£·É†·Éò"".  Why don't I see the original string?

These are my hibernate.cfg.xml settings:

```
<property name="hibernate.connection.useUnicode">
    true
</property>
<property name="hibernate.connection.characterEncoding">
    UTF-8
</property>
<property name="hibernate.connection.charSet">
    UTF-8
</property>
```

and this is my database connection string:

```
hibernate.connection.url = jdbc:mysql://localhost/mydatabase?autoReconnect=true&amp;useUnicode=true&amp;characterEncoding=UTF-8
```

Comment: Eclipse is my IDE, so standard out is showing in the Eclipse console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the console which is not configured to use `UTF-8` to *display* them. In case of Eclipse, you can configure its encoding  by *Window > Preferences > General > Workspace > Text File Encoding*. It should be set to `UTF-8`.

The `new OutputStreamWriter(System.out,"UTF-8");` only instructs the `OutputStreamWriter` which encoding to use to convert the written chars to bytes. It doesn't instruct the `System.out` console which encoding to use to convert them back from bytes to chars to *display* them.

Comment: What about netbeans? Is there any way to do as this in netbeans?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe its an issue with your JDBC driver? Try using a different one, see if the problem persists.

Comment: But I can persist Unicode just fine into the database, so it seems that the JDBC driver is fine.