# Hibernate Unicode by netbeans; Why saved in db as "?????"

Tags: java, mysql, database, hibernate, netbeans

I have a problem like [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2604588/why-do-unicode-characters-show-up-properly-in-database-but-as-when-printed-in). I am using netbeans 7.01 IDE and MySQL 5.2.35. I used this tricks but not effective:
I added this properties in my config file:

```
<property name="hibernate.connection.useUnicode">true</property>
<property name="hibernate.connection.characterEncoding">UTF-8</property>
```

and also:

> jdbc:mysql://localhost:3307/MY_DB_NAME?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=UTF-8

but not effective!

also I tried this java code to make java String Unicode and also it is futile:

```
    public static String toUTF8(String isoString) {
    String utf8String = null;
    if (null != isoString && !isoString.equals("")) {
        try {
            byte[] stringBytesISO = isoString.getBytes("ISO-8859-1");
            utf8String = new String(stringBytesISO, "UTF-8");
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            System.out.println("UnsupportedEncodingException is: " + e.getMessage());
            utf8String = isoString;
        }
    } else {
        utf8String = isoString;
    }
    return utf8String;
}
```

Can any one help me ?!

Answer (score 2):

Strings inside the JVM are already encoded correctly. There is no need to re-encode them.

Just pass the String instance to the `setString()` method in your PreparedStatement and you should be fine (provided your database *does* use UTF8)

Btw: `string.lenght() == 0` is much faster than `"".equals(string)`

Comment: I don't use PreparedStatement. I use hiberanateSession.save(anyObject) to save object in may dataBase

Answer (score 0):

check your database character set to be UTF-8 too: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-database.html

Comment: I had set it utf8-default collection before. I also tried to set it as  DEFAULT COLLATE utf8_general_ci. Not effective!

Answer (score 0):

You need to set db collation and table collation to *utf8_general_ci*. You can find [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-database.html) how to do this and make sure your database viewer supports utf-8 encoding, otherwise you will see unicode character as `???????`

Comment: Thank you But, When I want to do this by: ALTER SCHEMA `samim_iptv_epg`  DEFAULT COLLATE utf8_general_ci; But after Running this SQL script, The collate remains as utf8-default collation !!!!

Comment: can you create new database with utf-8 collation.??

Answer (score 0):

I faced same problem in Oracle when I persist the data. But fixed it in following way.

1. I came to know first I need to use `Universal version of Oracle`.
   So, I re-install my oracle with universal version. (check with MySql case)
2. Then I converted all string which are in UTF-8 to escape codes
   strings using `native2ascii` tool of java.
3. Then everything working fine as it get rendered properly in DB and
   as well as on view(browser).

`Note:` make sure your language pack is installed on your OS.

Hope this input might help you

Answer (score 0):

I also had such problem. I was using .jsp pages, and helped me to add following line in each .jsp file:

```
<%@ page pageEncoding="utf-8" %>
```